# Facebook geLoginUrl not working inside app

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I've been working on the following PHP project:

1) I'm developing an app in Facebook and when users reach
https://apps.facebook.com/app-name

I show them a Login Button, where in then need to agree to the user permissions and then return back to the redirect_uri which I specify.

This is working fine in my domain but not inside the app, what might be the reasons for this?

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/fbapp/login.php'
);  
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
```

I can see it reload to the same page ??

I can see the dialog and the user access permission window, if I access https://example.com/fbapp/ in browser. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Most likely you are redirecting to the login URL within the iframe that your app gets loaded into on facebook.com – but the login dialog can not be loaded into (i)frames, so you would need to redirect to it in the top window instance (via JS or a target attribute on your link). But why don’t you use the JS SDK to log the user in? It makes for a much nicer user experience on apps inside facebook.com, because it just overlays the page with a dialog.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, let me try this JS SDK